# Is it possible to insert controls such as Radio buttons, Checkboxes in report's bands?

Tags: checkbox, jasper-reports

I use *iReport 4.7.1*.

I would like to know: is it possible to insert controls such as radio buttons, checkbox inside iReport bands (in particular in Detail band)? I looked carefully among elements(controls in the palette) but there is no such controls there.

Also I checked "The iReport Ultimate guide" again there is nothing about these controls.

So I would like to know whether anybody has managed to create such controls via *iReport*.

My need is for a report where I have to use checkbox for students indicating the gender
something like this:

```
------------                ---------------
| checkBox1 |  MALE         |  CheckBox2  | FEMALE
------------                ---------------
```

So that based on (I think) some P{gender} parameter one should be filled.

Any idea?

Comment: How you can insert radio button in *txt*, *csv* or *pdf* files? Your question is unclear

Comment: No I don't mean to insert a real checkbox in the PDF file to allow the user to chose an option as an interactive form. It's just about the "appearance" , that is, when the document is printed, the gender should look like a "checked" checkbox beside either a MALE or FEMALE static text, depending on each person.

Answer (score 0):

One way to have checkbox in PDF is to use two image checked and unchecked, checkbox.

Create an *Image* element for checkbox and in the *Image Expression* (in the Image Properties info section) select the right image path by check P{gender} parameter, something like:

```
$F{GENDER}==1 ? ".../BoxChecked.bmp" : ".../BoxUnchecked.bmp"
```

in this case I've used a int parameter (GENDER) to store the info (for example 0 = male and 1 = female) and the two image path ".../BoxChecked.bmp" and ".../BoxUnchecked.bmp" where are store images. Images path could be relative o absolute.